# How to correctly add Google AMP .js files to my theme

Tags: theming, javascript

I'm using the Drupal AMP module,theme and library in Drupal 7

I'm using the AMP verification tool here [validator.ampproject.org](https://validator.ampproject.org/)

I have the amp-sidebar working fine except the JavaScript causes an error.
When adding the AMP internal js file I get the below error when validating.

```
<script async custom-element="amp-sidebar" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-sidebar-0.1.js"></script>
```

I get the following warning

**"The tag 'script' is disallowed except in specific forms."**

The second error i get is the following.
And as a result of that I get this error
  The tag 'amp-sidebar extension .js script' is missing or incorrect, but required by 'amp-sidebar'. Learn more.

I have included the full HTML file contents below if you want to run it through the validator to see the errors live, Just copy and paste the code.
[Pastebin of full Drupal AMP page](https://pastebin.com/165eB3dS)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the AMP component JS in the `<head>` section of your document, then it will be ok.

```
<script async custom-element="amp-sidebar" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-sidebar-0.1.js"></script>
```

> Extended components are loaded by including a  tag in the head of the document  https://www.ampproject.org/tr/docs/reference/spec

Comment: Thanks David you were exactly correct. I updated your answer to highlight that the script needs to be added in the html.tpl.php file for it to be added to the head of the document.